# 電圧についての質問

Tags: 電子回路

書籍「CPUの創りかた」を読み進めており、下記のような回路が出てきたのですが、なぜA地点の電圧が2.44Vなのかが分かりません。

自分で調べてみて、キルヒホップの第2法則を使うのかなと思いましたが解法を思いつきません。

是非ご教授よろしくお願い致します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 電気・電子回路の質問はここではオフトピックですね。[ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) 英語のサイトならこんなの [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) がありますが、日本語でそれらを対象としているサイトは無かったような？ 詳しい個人・関連企業・あるいはなんでも扱っているようなサイトに移動した方が良いでしょう。[電子工作に詳しい方に質問](https://okwave.jp/qa/q9777249.html), [「電子回路」に関するQ＆A - Yahoo!知恵袋](https://chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/search?p=%E9%9B%BB%E5%AD%90%E5%9B%9E%E8%B7%AF&type=tag&tnum=1)

Answer (score 1):

オフトピックだと思いますが考え方だけ、
下半分は10kΩと200kΩの合成抵抗になります。
なので、抵抗値は9.5238KΩ。
上の抵抗10KΩと9.5238KΩで電圧を分割すると
A点の電圧は5*9.5238÷(10+9.5238) = 2.439V ≒ 2.44Vになります。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ずっと悩んでいたのですが、解法をご教授して頂き自分で計算してみて納得がいきました。ありがとうございます。