# コンデンサの放電の際の動きについて

Tags: 電子回路

現在、「CPUの創りかた」を読んでいます。
この際、コンデンサを使っての放電の際の電流の動きがわかりません。

スイッチがONの時に、コンデンサに充電された電流が手動クロックの方向のグラウンドに流れることは分かります。
この時、電源に繋がっている5Vから出力される電流の挙動です。

書籍では、スイッチONの際に5Vの回路に関しては「この時は無意味は部分」と書かれていますが、実際にはスイッチON時には、5Vの電源からスイッチ方向に対して、電流が流れているのでしょうか？
またこの際スイッチON時のグラウンドに対して、コンデンサの放電の電流と電圧５Vが出力する電流がかかっているのでしょうか？
その時の電流の値と電圧の値はどのような計算で求まるのでしょうか？

ご教授よろしくお願い致します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: [過去の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/88826) でも同様のコメントが付いているかと思いますが、当サイトは主にプログラミングに関する質問を扱っているため、電子回路の話は話題の範囲外と判断される可能性があります。参考ヘルプ: [ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

もちろん「無意味な部分」であるところの `+5V-1kΩ-スイッチ-GND` にも電流が流れています。スイッチ ON 時のスイッチの抵抗値はミリオーム以下なので 1kΩ に比してほぼ無視できて、よって「無意味な電流」として 5mA が流れる計算になります（この電流は回路的に何の役にも立っていないので本当に無意味です。電池機器でこんな設計していたらぶん殴られます）

スイッチに流れる電流は 1kΩ に流れる電流と 10kΩ に流れる電流の和です（キルヒホッフの法則） 1kΩ に流れる電流は 5mA で一定 10kΩ に流れる電流はキャパシタ 10uF からの放電電流並びに `CLOCK` の先から流れ込む/流れ出す電流の和ということになります。

`CLOCK` の先が CMOS マイコンの入力端子なら DC 漏れ電流は pA 以下なので放電電流に比して小さいのでこちらも無視できるため図示されていないようです。

Comment: 774RR様　
大変分かりやすいコメントありがとうございます。
電流が回路的に役に立っていないことと、キルヒホップの法則を使うことが大変タメになりました。
頂いたコメントを元に自分で調べて勉強したいと思います。

また是非質問に答えて頂けると幸いです。

Comment: この回路で `CLOCK` は積分回路に直接接続されているので、普通の CMOS 回路をつなぐと動作不安定になります。シュミットトリガ式波形整形回路が必要だったり、今時のマイコンだとシュミットトリガ内蔵入力ピンがあるのでそういうピンを選定する必要があります。要注意っスね。

Comment: 774RR様　追伸ありがとうございます。まだ自分がコメントして頂いた内容までの力がないため、学習してまたこちらをご参考にさせて頂きたいと思います。心優しい説明本当にありがとうございます。

Comment: 774RR様　追加で質問で答えて頂きたいのですが、読み進めていてCLOCKの先に２つのシュミットトリガを組んだ回路を見ました。電源をONにすれば、CLOCKの先の先からLを出力する回路であると書いているのですが、ONを押した時にはCLOCK側には電気が流れずグラウンドと繋がっているコンデンサの方向に電気が流れるのではないかと思います。OFFにした時も同じで、スイッチONの方向へ電流が流れていって、CLOCK側には電流が流れないと思います。電圧が溜まっているのは、コンデンサ自体であると思います。しかし、この私の考えではCLOCK側に対して回路を作っている意味がないので、ご教授お願いします。　よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 回路図見ないと答えられないので（一部の人からは推奨されなさそうですが）別質問にしていただくと幸いです。まあオペアンプなり CMOS な IC の入力電流は微小なので無視できるというか無視しちゃっているってあたりかも。

Comment: 774RR様　コメントありがとうございます。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/90145/%e3%82%b3%e3%83%b3%e3%83%87%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b5%e3%81%a8%e9%9b%bb%e5%9c%a7%e3%81%a8%e9%9b%bb%e6%b5%81%e3%81%ae%e9%96%a2%e4%bf%82%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6

こちらの方に新しい質問を掲載致しました。お忙しいとは思いますが、ご教授して頂けるととても励みになるのと有り難いです。
よろしくお願い致します。