# コンデンサと電圧と電流の関係について

Tags: 電子回路

前回の質問、[コンデンサの放電の際の動きについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/89878) の続きです。

74HC14やRESETに対しては、電流は流れているのでしょうか？
もし流れているとしたらいくつでどういう計算でしょうか？またこれは並列回路ですか？
前提として、リセットスイッチがOFFの時には、コンデンサに対して電流が流れコンデンサに対して電圧が溜まっていると思います。
リセットスイッチがONの時には、コンデンサからリセットスイッチを通したグラウンドに対して電流が流れていっていると思います。

そもそもこの回路は何が目的でしょうか？コンデンサに溜まった電圧がいくらか調べたいのでしょうか？(電流ではなく)
このシュミットトリガは電圧計のような目的で使っているだけでしょうか？

電子回路というものは、電流を流したいのではなく、ある物体や目的物に対して電圧をいくらかかけるかが重要なのでしょうか？
電圧は電流を押し出すものだと思っていますが、勉強すればするほど電圧と電流の関係並びに、
この回路が何をしたいのが分からなくなってきました。
言葉足らずだとは思いますが、ご教授の程よろしくお願い致します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

まず [CMOS](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMOS) ってのは特性の反対な [MOSFET](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET) を２つペアにしたものです。 MOSFET の構造上、ゲートってのはキャパシタ相当と思ってよくて、よって電圧が一定である条件では充放電が生じない＝電流が流れないという特徴があります（厳密には漏れ電流が必ず生じるので pA ピコアンペアくらいは流れるのですが、この例では無視できる）なので「基本動作を理解する」という点においては電流のことは忘れてしまって問題ないです。電圧だけ考えればOK

電圧に変化がないときは電流が流れない＝消費電力が少ないってことなので、今どきのマイコンはすべてこの CMOS 構造になっています。その昔の [TTL](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor-transistor_logic) とか [ECL](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A8%E3%83%9F%E3%83%83%E3%82%BF%E7%B5%90%E5%90%88%E8%AB%96%E7%90%86) ってのは電流で制御するので消費電力が大きく、すなわち発熱するので今ではすたれてしまいました（ ECL で作られた [Cray-1](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cray-1) は基板がフロン冷媒に浸かっているありさま）

で、この回路なんですが、その目的は
・なにかのトリガ（スイッチを押す）を機に、一定時間 L を出力したのち H に戻る信号を出す
というものです。名称からして「リセット信号」のようですね。書いてある通り、リセット信号＝ L でリセットするようなマイコンがあるとき、そのリセット信号を与えるためのものです。
# リセットとは全ハードウエアを初期状態に戻してプログラムを最初から実行するものです。

マイコンソフトがバグっているなどの理由によりリセットをかける目的で、このリセットスイッチを押すと「リセット信号」が L になります。リセット回路が動作するにもそれなりの時間が必要なので、しばらく L を維持しなければなりません。そののちリセット信号が H になるとリセット状態が解除され、プログラムは最初から動作をやり直すことになります。

んで、説明のための説明としてこのような回路が書かれていますが「パワーオンリセット」（と図にはある）のための回路としては、この回路図は絶対に実用してはいけません。パワーオン中ならびにパワーオフ中（電源電圧が所定の電圧未満になる状況）では 74HC14 も正しく動作する保証がないためです。

パワーオンリセット（パワーオフリセット）周りはデジタルであるはずのマイコン回路のなかで例外的に純アナログな回路なので、ある意味ノウハウの塊です。とりあえずこの回路図は「説明のための説明」「解説のための解説」として割り切ってください（ソフトウエアの入門書でも初心者は詳細を知らなくてもよさそうなところを解説省略している場合がありますが、ここはまさにそんな感じ）繰り返しますが実用する回路にこんな設計絶対にしないでください。うまくリセットがかからないなどの不具合が必ず発生します。

---

ちょっと追加

デジタル回路というかデジタル信号ってのは (CMOS の場合) 一定電圧 VIH 以上を H と呼び、同様一定電圧 VIL 以下を L と呼ぶわけです。なので VIL より上 VIH より下の中途半端な電圧は使用禁止です。無限に高速な信号なんてものは作れないので、この中途半端な電圧がかかる時間は０にできません。なので誤動作しない程度の短時間でなければなりません。積分回路の電圧はゆっくり変化するので、この使用禁止電圧にいる時間が長くなり誤動作します。
シュミットトリガというのは例外的に「ゆっくり変化する信号を入力しても誤動作しない」回路です（もちろんその分部品数が増えたり動作が遅くなったりする）出力は普通にデジタル信号になるので、非シュミットトリガな回路にも安全に与えることができるわけです。

---

コメントが別な質問なのでここで対処（オイラなら使わない日本語表記なのでこの解釈であっているか微妙に不安）

> コンデンサに溜まった電圧を測るためにVoutとしてシュミットトリガの方向へ電圧がlowかhighかを出力していると考えたのですが正しいでしょうか？

積分回路の電圧をシュミットトリガが測定している、という意味で Yes 電圧計やオシロスコープを接続する際に「電圧をオシロスコープに出力している」とは普通言わないと思うが、実態はそう。

> シュミットトリガへは電流が流れない

これも同様、電圧計やオシロスコープに/から電流が流れていると普通には言わないだけのこと。０かよ、絶対に０かよ！と言われれば微小に流れてはいる。けれども無視できる程度ってこと。動作原理の理解のためには無視できるものはあっさり無視しちゃうのが吉。

バケツの中にたまっているのは電荷
電荷の高さが電圧
電荷の流れが電流（よって高いところから低いところにしか流れない）
ちょろちょろ流すかドバーっと流すかを制御するのが抵抗

Comment: 774RR様　大変心優しいコメントありがとうございます。またしても自分の勉強不足で分からないことばかりですが、頂いた情報を元に勉強して行きたいと思います。

頂いたことを元に自分で考えると、コンデンサに溜まった電圧を測るためにVoutとしてシュミットトリガの方向へ電圧がlowかhighかを出力していると考えたのですが正しいでしょうか？

Comment: また、シュミットトリガへは電流が流れないと説明をいただきましたが、
コンデンサに溜まった電圧がスイッチを押した際にグラウンドへと流れると考えれば良いですか？
電圧はバケツに入った水の集合で、その水がチョロチョロ流れていくのが電流だとイメージしています。

Comment: 774RR様　いつもコメントの追加ありがとうございます。ご教授して頂いたことが自分の理解に大変役立っております。
また別の質問で、クロックジェネレータの回路について疑問が出たのでお時間ある時に答えていたければ非常にありがたいです。よろしくお願い致します。[クロックジェネレータ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/90285/%e3%82%af%e3%83%ad%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%82%b8%e3%82%a7%e3%83%8d%e3%83%ac%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%81%ae%e5%9b%9e%e8%b7%af%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6cpu%e3%81%ae%e5%89%b5%e3%82%8a%e3%81%8b%e3%81%9f)

Answer (score 1):

それはスイッチによるチャタリングを除去する回路です
スイッチの入切り時の波形の乱れを、CR時定数回路により吸収し、シュミットトリガゲートの出力にはバタつきのないHi/Lo波形を出力します

74HC14の入力ピンは電流は流れません。
なので、各電流、電圧に関しては以下を読んでいただければわかるかと。

[【RC直列回路とは】時定数、電流、電圧、ラプラス変換](https://algorithm.joho.info/denki-denshi/rc-circuit-time-constant/)

Comment: y_waiwai様　コメントありがとうございます。
コンデンサに溜まった電圧を入力するために、シュミットトリガゲートを設置していると考えました。

Comment: 提示したリンクにあるように、コンデンサの電圧はなだらかに変化していきます。普通のゲートでは、このなだらかな電圧変化でバタついた出力になる可能性があります
これをシュミットトリガで受ければバタつくことはありません。まあ、ここらへんはこの質問からは外れるので、ご自分で調べてみてください