# クロックジェネレータの回路について

Tags: 電子回路

現在、CPUの創りかたの書籍を行っています。
その際、下記の①から③への回路の変換が分かりません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

③のシュミットトリガの先には以下のように、B地点やC地点を表すためにもう一つのシュミットトリガが構成されているのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上記の画像の回路だともし仮定すれば①の回路では、A地点にあるシュミットトリガから出た先とB地点が交差しているのに(B地点は抵抗と繋がっているはず)、上記の画像や②の変形した回路では全くそのような回路に見えません。

①のC地点と近いシュミットトリガの出力先のであるC地点も同じです。(コンデンサと繋がっていない)

この①から②や、①から③への回路の変形の鍵は、回路が交差しているということよりも、その地点においての電圧がHighかLowか表すことをしたいだけなのでしょうか？
回路に関して全くの初心者なのでご教授して頂けるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> この①から②や、①から③への回路の変形の鍵は、回路が交差しているということよりも、その地点においての電圧がHighかLowか表すことをしたいだけなのでしょうか？

その通りだと思います。まずAの電圧がL（＝GND）の場合を考えると、B・Cの電位が定まるので、その情報を使って回路を書き換えています。図1の左のシュミットトリガの出力とBを切り、Bを「どこからかやってきた5V」に置き換え、右のシュミットトリガとB・Cを切断して、「なかったこと」にしています。図2のB・Cは抵抗とコンデンサでつながっているので、これで電位差を保てます。

電気「回路」はループでできているので、そのままだと、どこから始まってどこで終わるのかわかりづらい場合があります。物理的には終わりも始まりもないのですが、人間の理解のためにループを切断して考えてみるのは有効な手段です。図3を左から右へと読むと、「5V/GNDからシュミットトリガに入り、右へ出力される」ことが明瞭になっているのがわかると思います。

Comment: sei0o様　大変分かりやすいコメントありがとうございます。　ループ回路に初めて出会ったのでどうすれば良いか分かりませんでしたが理解できました。非常に励みになります。またご質問に答えて頂ければありがたいです。

Comment: sei0o様　この質問の続きで[新しい疑問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/90458/%e3%82%af%e3%83%ad%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%82%b8%e3%82%a7%e3%83%8d%e3%83%ac%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%81%ae%e3%82%b3%e3%83%b3%e3%83%87%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b5%e3%81%ae%e5%8b%95%e3%81%8d%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6)が生じました。ご回答いただけると幸いです

Answer (score 2):

CMOS 出力段トランジスタは飽和状態で使うため下の図のように MOSFET を単なるスイッチに近似することができます（ TTL/ECL ではこういう近似をするとダメ）

- H 出力中は +5V と出力が短絡されている
- L 出力中は GND と出力が短絡されている
- スイッチングの最中を過渡状態と呼ぶけど、原則上アーム下アームとも OFF する
- 過渡状態で上アーム下アームとも ON することは厳禁

[image: CMOS出力段の考え方]

また同様 CMOS は電圧入力（入力側で電流が流れないと考えてよい）ということで１図のB点において、前段 HC14 の出力が H であるという**前提を置く**なら

- 前段 HC14 の出力が H = +5V 側のスイッチが短絡という近似ができる
- 後段 HC14 の入力には電流が流れない＝回路的に切断する近似ができる
- 後段 HC14 の出力が L = GND 側のスイッチが短絡という近似ができる

となると２，３のように変形して考えて構わないわけです。

では前段 HC14 の出力が L であるという前提を置いたらどんな回路に近似できるか自分でやってみてください。すると充放電を繰り返して発振すると理解できるはずです。

質問「〇〇が△△につながっていない」ように思えるの答えは、△△が +5V/GND につながっているという近似ができる結果、〇〇は +5V/GND につながっている考えてよいから、ということになるでしょう。

で、これは典型的シュミットインバータ CR 発振回路ですね。デジタル IC をアナログ回路で使うという特殊な例と言っていいでしょう。インバータ２つ使いなのがちょっと無駄かも？[１個でも問題ない例](http://bbradio.sakura.ne.jp/7414/7414.html) これを実用するマイコンでのクロック源とするのは CR の精度がなさすぎで無理があります。実用上はどうしても水晶振動子とかセラロックとかにならざるを得ない感じがします。

Comment: 774RR様　いつもコメントありがとうございます。図の通りに必ず回路を作成しなければならないと思っていたので、近似の結果を生み出す回路を作れば良いことを初めて知ったのでとてもタメになります。また他の場所で電気回路の質問の是非に意見されているところを拝見させて頂きまして本当に感謝しています。ありがとうございます。
また書籍を読み進めていくうちに新しい疑問ができたので、ご回答して頂けると非常に助かります。[コンデンサの動き](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/90458/%e3%82%af%e3%83%ad%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%82%b8%e3%82%a7%e3%83%8d%e3%83%ac%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%81%ae%e3%82%b3%e3%83%b3%e3%83%87%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b5%e3%81%ae%e5%8b%95%e3%81%8d%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6)
是非よろしくお願い致します

Answer (score 1):

①の回路では、ゲートの出力（BとC）は、High（５V）か、Low(0V)のいずれしかありません
で、CがHighの場合はAとBはどうなるか、CがLowの場合はAとBはどうなるかわかるでしょうか。

Comment: y_waiwai様　ご教授ありがとうございます。 CがHighの時は、AもHighでBがLowだと思います。一方で、CがLowの時はAがLowでBがHighだと思います。Aに対してシュミットトリガであるnot回路でBの出力が反転し、Bの出力に対してnot回路で反転し、AとCが同じHighかLowで、BがAとCの値に対して反転すると思っています。いかがでしょうか？

Comment: この回路のポイントは、コンデンサと抵抗で時定数回路を作っているところにあります

Comment: この回路のポイントは、コンデンサと抵抗で時定数回路を作っているところにあります
CがHighのときはBはLowとなります。で、Aは、というと、CがHighになった瞬間にはAはHighとなり、CRの時定数回路により、だんだんとAの電圧は下がっていきます
ある程度Aの電圧が下がると、BはHighとなってCはLowになります
こうなるとAの電圧は、その瞬間はLowとなりますが、今度は時間がたつにつれ電圧は上がっていきます。
で、ある程度電圧が上がると、BはLowになり、、と動作を繰り返していくことになります

Comment: で、質問文の②というのは、このCがLowになった時の状態の説明を行っていますね

Comment: y_waiwai様　ありがとうございます。[コンデンサの動き](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/90458/%e3%82%af%e3%83%ad%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%82%b8%e3%82%a7%e3%83%8d%e3%83%ac%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%81%ae%e3%82%b3%e3%83%b3%e3%83%87%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b5%e3%81%ae%e5%8b%95%e3%81%8d%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6)
この回路の反転した時の動きが分からなく新しい質問を作りました。是非ご意見頂けると有り難いです。よろしくお願い致します。