# クロックジェネレータのコンデンサの動きについて

Tags: 電子回路

[前回](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/90285/%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%83%8D%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%81%AE%E5%9B%9E%E8%B7%AF%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)の質問の続きです。

コンデンサに2.5Vの電圧が溜まった時に、回路が変形します。
その際、以下の図の回路が分かりません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

"ここは、7.5Vです"という理由が分かりません。
コンデンサに溜まった電圧が2.5Vで、電源からの5Vの電圧で合わせて7.5Vだと思うのですが、
コンデンサの性質は電気を流さないことだと思います。

なのに、なぜ電気を流して7.5Vになるのでしょうか？
また[前回](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/90285/%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%83%8D%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%81%AE%E5%9B%9E%E8%B7%AF%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)では、プラス側のコンデンサに接続していましたが今回はマイナス側のコンデンサに接続されています。
このようなことは可能なのでしょうか？ YoutubeやGoogle検索で調べても上手く見つけれないので
ご教授して頂ける方がいましたら是非よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 3):

> コンデンサに溜まった電圧が2.5Vで、電源からの5Vの電圧で合わせて7.5Vだと思うのですが、
> コンデンサの性質は電気を流さないことだと思います。
> なのに、なぜ電気を流して7.5Vになるのでしょうか？

あなたの論理は

- コンデンサは電流を流さない
- 電圧が加算されるには電流が流れる必要がある。
- したがって、電流を流さないコンデンサを繋いでも電圧は加算されないはずだ。

ということかと思います。前提2つが間違っています。

第一に、コンデンサは電流を流します。
直流を流さない、
直流/交流という表現は曖昧なのでより正確に言えば
一定電圧をかけ続けて定常状態に達すれば流さなくなるだけです。
電源電圧が一定であっても過渡状態を考えれば流れますし、
電源電圧が変化すればもちろん流れます。

第二に、電流が流れることと電圧が加算されることは関係ありません。
全く電流を通さないが、両端に2.5Vの電位差を発生させる仮想的な素子でも7.5Vになります。
もちろん、コンデンサが充電されるには電流を流さなければなりませんが、
それはあくまで充電時の話です。

> また前回では、プラス側のコンデンサに接続していましたが今回はマイナス側のコンデンサに接続されています。
> このようなことは可能なのでしょうか？

プラス/マイナス側のコンデンサに接続しているという表現が何を指しているのかわかりませんが(コンデンサは1つしか無い)、
前回と同様、考えたい場所の電圧(今回はA点)を電圧が既知の場所(B,C点)を使って回路を近似しているだけです。

> またこの回路が7.5Vになるのは、最初の電位が2.5V溜まった状態でさらに5V溜まっているからだと思う

何をいいたいのか読み取れませんでした。
7.5Vになる理由はコンデンサの両端に2.5Vの電位差が生じるまで充電して、コンデンサの電位が低い方の電極に5Vを接続したからです。

> これはグラウンドのある回路は電位の基準が0Vだから全体の回路はMax5Vだと思うのですが、この回路は電位差によってMax7.5Vなのでしょうか？

何をいいたいのか読み取れませんでした。Maxとは?
とりあえず、回路の作りによっては電源電圧以上の(GND基準の)電圧が回路に現れることはあります。

> コンデンサにおいてこの図の回路では、コンデンサのマイナス側に電源がつながっていますが、前回の回路ではコンデンサのプラス側に電源がついていることと、コンデンサには極性があってプラス側に電源をつけると私は認識しているのですがいかがでしょうか？

コンデンサには極性があるものも存在するのが話をややこしくするのですが、

- コンデンサの極性と電源をつける方は関係ない
- そもそも今回においてはコンデンサの極性は関係ない

まず電極があるコンデンサの場合、プラス側に電源をつけるという制約はありません。ただコンデンサの極性と逆向きに電圧がかからないようにすればそれでいいです。

次にそもそも、この回路のコンデンサが極性付きかはどうでもいいです。
コンデンサの本質的なところは溜めた電荷に比例した電圧が現れることで、極性があるかは回路の動作原理を説明する上ではどうでもいいのです。

さらに、前回の説明を見る限りコンデンサに+/-が書いてあるのは極性表示ではなく、
ただ単にそちら側の端子に+/-の電荷が溜まっているという表示のように思えます

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。　こちらの回路は、そもそも交流なのでしょうか？(私は直流だと認識していたのですが)直流だから電圧が足されていて7.5Vだと思います。
またこの回路が7.5Vになるのは、最初の電位が2.5V溜まった状態でさらに5V溜まっているからだと思うのですが、これはグラウンドのある回路は電位の基準が0Vだから全体の回路はMax5Vだと思うのですが、この回路は電位差によってMax7.5Vなのでしょうか？

コンデンサにおいてこの図の回路では、コンデンサのマイナス側に電源がつながっていますが、[前回の回路](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/90285/%e3%82%af%e3%83%ad%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%82%b8%e3%82%a7%e3%83%8d%e3%83%ac%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%81%ae%e5%9b%9e%e8%b7%af%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6/90300#90300)ではコンデンサのプラス側に電源がついていることと、コンデンサには極性があってプラス側に電源をつけると私は認識しているのですがいかがでしょうか？
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: コメントについて追記しました。

Comment: 分かりやすいコメントありがとうございます。ご教授して頂いた内容で理解できました。またこれに付随する次の質問も生じましたので答えて頂けると幸いです。
 [コンデンサの電圧の質問の続き](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/90611/%e3%82%af%e3%83%ad%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%82%b8%e3%82%a7%e3%83%8d%e3%83%ac%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%81%ae%e3%82%b3%e3%83%b3%e3%83%87%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b5%e3%81%ae%e9%9b%bb%e5%9c%a7%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6cpu%e3%81%ae%e5%89%b5%e3%82%8a%e3%81%8b%e3%81%9f)

Answer (score 1):

前の回答でも書きましたが「電気回路は変形してより理解の簡単な形に近似することができる」のではありますが、「近似の前提となる条件が成立する短時間 (数フェムト秒～数ナノ秒) のみ、その近似は成立する」ということはしっかり意識しておいてください。時間が経過すると今立てた近似モデルは不成立になり、別の近似モデルを立てなきゃならなくなります（というのを「動的に解析する」という）
# 今どきの CPU は 1GHz 超で動作する（＝クロック保持時間は 1nsec 未満）っス。

> コンデンサにはすでに 2.5V が充電されている

というのは、著者が解説のために設けた「ある瞬間の前提条件」です。よってその瞬間の前あるいは後ではこの条件は成立しなくなります。決して「ずっと 2.5V を維持している」わけではないのですがこの辺大丈夫？本の解説は、たまたまコンデンサの電圧が 2.5V である数フェムト秒～数ナノ秒のみ成立します。大事なことなので ry)

# 英語ではコンデンサという単語は凝縮器と解釈されます。キャパシタのほうが適切ですが、この解説中は原著に従ってコンデンサと呼称しましょう。

> コンデンサの性質は電気を流さないことだと思います。

ここも誤解があるというか（誤解というと失礼ですけど）。中一生が二乗したら負になる数なんかないですよねと言っている感じ。

コンデンサの性質は「両端の電圧差を一定に維持しようとする」です。だけど周りの回路がそれを許さないよう作ってあるので、充電＝電圧差が大きくなる、放電＝電圧差が小さくなる、を行うのです。コンデンサには電流が流れるんですよ。

で、前回同様「電源電圧は恒常的に一定とみなしてよい」「 CMOS IC の出力段は電源と短絡していると近似して良い」から提示の近似回路図が得られます。

Warning: [TC74HC14AP](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/jp/semiconductor/product/general-purpose-logic-ics/detail.TC74HC14AP.html) のマニュアルによると入力端子に掛けてよい電圧は `Vcc+0.5V` なので `VCC=5.0V` のとき `7.5V` がかかってしまう回路は０点です。オイラなら回路レビューで再設計を命じます。

---

オイラの言いたいことはだいたい全部 @ozwk さんに言い尽くされてしまったので別方面から

モデル（というかモデル化理解）について慣れていないせいか誤解があるようです

> コンデンサの性質は電気を流さないこと

これも「そういうモデルが成立しているときは、その通り」で、一定電圧を印加し続けた後にはそのように解釈していいです。どの程度の時間が経過したら一定とみなしてよいかを「時定数」と呼び、式では `τ=CR` ですね。

では一定電圧でない場合（電圧が揺動している場合）は上記モデルは成立しないということになります。電流を流さないモデルが成立しないのだから、電流を流せる（コンデンサに電流が流れる）モデルが成立します。

放電済みコンデンサを電源に並列つなぎして充電する⇔充電済みコンデンサを電源に直列つなぎしてより高い電圧を**一時的に**出す、を切り替える回路を[チャージポンプ](https://analogista.jp/chargepump/)と呼びますが、普通に多用されています。 `RS232` の出力ドライバICはこれを使って [-10V - +10V] な信号を作っています。

AC/DC ってのも同様、理解の仕方が違うというか。 AC ってのは基準点から見て電圧が正負に振れるものをいいます。この「基準点」はモデルを立てる人が任意に決めてよくて、回路上 `GND` と書かれている場所である必然はありません。

`V(t) = 0.0V + 2.5 * sin(ωt)` だと基準点 `0.0V` な AC (-2.5V - +2.5V な波形)
(であることには納得していただけるものと思う)
`V(t) = 2.5V + 2.5 * sin(ωt)` だと基準点 `2.5V` な AC (0.0V - 5.0V な波形)
(普通はこれを DC とは呼ばない：こちらが納得できるか否か)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。　他の方が、「電流が流れることと電圧が加算されることは関係ありません。」と回答して頂いてるのですが、なぜ充電は行われるのでしょうか？電流が流れるから電位が溜まって行って電位差が生じて、電圧が大きくなると思うのですがいかがでしょうか？
逆に放電は、電流が流出して電位が無くなり電圧差が無くなると思うでしょうが正しいでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。頂いた内容が勉強不足な自分には難しすぎて理解が出来ない部分がありますがイメージできます。また次の質問が生じましたので、宜しければ答えて頂けると幸いです。[コンデンサの電圧の疑問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/90611/%e3%82%af%e3%83%ad%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%82%b8%e3%82%a7%e3%83%8d%e3%83%ac%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%81%ae%e3%82%b3%e3%83%b3%e3%83%87%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b5%e3%81%ae%e9%9b%bb%e5%9c%a7%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6cpu%e3%81%ae%e5%89%b5%e3%82%8a%e3%81%8b%e3%81%9f)

Answer (score 0):

> コンデンサの性質は電気を流さないことだと思います。

充電、放電する場合に電流が流れます
充電、放電が完了すると電流は流れなくなります

コンデンサに２．５V充電されたあと、０V側の端子に５Vを加えると、その瞬間は７．５Vになってしまいます
ましかし、その電圧もほんの一瞬だけ、で、コンデンサの放電とともに下がっていくことになります

こういうアナログ回路の動作を理解しようとするなら、オシロスコープを買ってきて、実際にその回路を組んで各部分の電圧波形を実際に見てみると理解が早いかと思います。

＃ところが、実際にその回路を組んで電圧を見てみると、７．５Vにはならなかったりするのは、回路図睨んでるだけではわからないですね

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。頂いたコメントをもとに理解できました。
また次の疑問が生まれましたので、答えて頂けると幸いです。
[次の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/90611/%e3%82%af%e3%83%ad%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%82%b8%e3%82%a7%e3%83%8d%e3%83%ac%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%81%ae%e3%82%b3%e3%83%b3%e3%83%87%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b5%e3%81%ae%e9%9b%bb%e5%9c%a7%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6cpu%e3%81%ae%e5%89%b5%e3%82%8a%e3%81%8b%e3%81%9f)