# クロックジェネレータのコンデンサの電圧について

Tags: 電子回路

[前回](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/90458/%e3%82%af%e3%83%ad%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%82%b8%e3%82%a7%e3%83%8d%e3%83%ac%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%81%ae%e3%82%b3%e3%83%b3%e3%83%87%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b5%e3%81%ae%e5%8b%95%e3%81%8d%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6)の質問の続きです。

A地点の電圧が、-2.5Vから7.5Vの間であると書籍(CPUの創りかた)には書いてあるのですが理由が分かりません。
元々、コンデンサには電圧が2.5V溜まっておりそのコンデンサに電源電圧である5Vが加えられて、7.5Vになることは分かります。

しかし、放電の際になぜ-2.5Vになるか分かりません。
元々コンデンサに溜まっていた2.5Vと電源電圧の5Vを放電して0Vになって終わりだと思うのですが、
なぜ、-2.5Vになるのでしょうか？
またそもそもコンデンサに溜まった2.5Vしか放電出来ないと思うのですが、電源電圧分も放電できるのでしょうか？
私の仮定は、5V(7.5V - 2.5V) <= A地点　<= 7.5V(2.5V + 5V) と思うのですが
これは書籍の内容と照らし合わせると誤りです。

書籍の中では、-2.5V(2.5V - 5V) <= A地点　<= 7.5V(2.5V + 5V)で放電の際に電源電圧分をさらに引いていると思うのですが、なぜでしょうか？

ぜひご教授よろしくお願い致します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ここからA地点の画像の追加
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 放電の際になぜ-2.5Vになるか分かりません。

A点が対GNDで-2.5Vになるのがわからないという話なら、
C点が5Vを出力していて、C点から見たA点の電圧(コンデンサの両端)が-2.5VになったときにA点は2.5Vになるわけで、
となると閾値を下回りますからB点の出力がL(0)からH(5)に切り替わって、
そうなるとC点の出力がH(5)からL(0)に切り替わって、
C点から見たA点の電圧はコンデンサにより-2.5Vのままに保持されてC点が0Vになるので、
A点が対GNDで-2.5V(=0+(-2.5))になります。

ですから、

> 書籍の中では、-2.5V(2.5V - 5V) <= A地点　<= 7.5V(2.5V + 5V)で放電の際に電源電圧分をさらに引いていると思うのですが、なぜでしょうか？

「放電の際に電源電圧分をさらに引いている」というのは認識が誤っています。
(2.5V-5V)ではなく、(0+(-2.5V))です

C点出力がHからLの遷移する様子を図に描きました。
[image: C点出力がHからLの遷移する様子]

Comment: ozwk様　図まで書いて頂き本当にありがとう御座います。 " A点が対GNDで-2.5Vになるのがわからないという話なら、 C点が5Vを出力していて、C点から見たA点の電圧(コンデンサの両端)が-2.5VになったときにA点は2.5Vになるわけで、 "というところが分かりません。1行目の"A点が対GNDで-2.5Vになる"というのはコンデンサから2.5V放電されているときに、A地点から見るとGNDに対して-2.5Vなのでしょうか？　コンデンサが放電されると0Vで終わりの気がします。　 頂いた図を元に上から順番に自分が考えてることを列挙させて頂きます。
①コンデンサに2.5V充電されているかつ電源電圧5Vからの供給あり
②コンデンサから2.5V放電されたので、電源電圧5Vのみ
③と④で、なぜコンデンサから-2.5V放出されているのか分からないため、下の画像２つが分からないです。理由をご教授して頂くと大変嬉しいです。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: "コンデンサが放電されると0Vで終わりの気がします" が現実と違うからです。

Comment: 「充電」「放電」という言葉のイメージに引っ張られ過ぎなのかなと思います。たしかに日常生活(例えば充電池)では、充電した分しか放電できないので、コンデンサも似たようなものと考えそうですが、実際はそうではありません。コンデンサにおいては放電も充電も実質同じです。

Comment: コンデンサの両端の電圧が2.5Vから負になる過程は放電というよりは逆向きに充電しているというのがより正確かもしれません。

Comment: ozwk様　コメントありがとうございます。つまり、コンデンサ自体は、2.5Vまで充電でき、-2.5Vまで放電できるということと理解致しました。最初自分は、2.5Vまでコンデンサが充電できるならその電荷を解放することでに0Vになると思っていましたが、プラス方向にも、マイナス方向にもそれぞれ2.5V充電、放電できるということなのですね。ありがとうございます。またもう少し書籍を読み進めて分からないことがあれば質問させて頂くので宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: ozwk様　A点の電圧の軌跡の画像を追加したのですが、頂いたコメントを元に私の考えが合ってるか確認して頂きたいです。まず、①で-2.5Vに放電されていたコンデンサに2.5V充電される。②2.5Vのしきい値を超えたので、出力がLowからHighになり5V追加されて7.5Vになる。③7.5Vから、コンデンサの放電が始まりコンデンサ自体の電圧が-2.5VになりA地点としては2.5Vになる。④しきい値の2.5VになったのでHighからLowになり-5VされてA地点は-2.5Vになる。　　全て緩やかな曲線の部分は、コンデンサの充放電で、極端に電圧が変わっている所はHighとLowにそれぞれジャンプしているからだと思います。コンデンサの電圧の動きは、常に -2.5V <= コンデンサの電圧　<= 2.5Vの範囲を動いていると思います。　回答の是非をお願い致します。

Comment: そんな感じです。

Answer (score 1):

なぜに `2.5V` なる謎の数値が突然出てきて、当たり前のように使われているのか謎だったんだけどなんとなくわかった・・・ 1/2 Vdd のことだ。非シュミット入力な場合の話だ。

短い答え：
その本のその章、いろいろ誤っているので読まなくていいです。どのみち一般人が普通に手に入れることのできる C/R の精度だと誤差が大きすぎて実用になりません。忘れ去ってください。
読むべきはすでにリンクした　[シュミットインバータによる発振回路](http://bbradio.sakura.ne.jp/7414/7414.html)

長い答えがいりますか？　必要ならコメントでもしてください。

質問に対する回答：
電圧＝任意の二点間の電位差。別にどこか基準点を取る義務はないです。身長 160cm の人がヒール 5cm の靴を履いたら、地上－頭上は 165cm になる（身長は 160cm のまま変わっていません）のと同じ。 5V 電源に 5V 充電済みコンデンサを上乗せしたら 10V になるの、納得できないですか？同様 GND に 5V 充電済みコンデンサを逆乗せしたら -5V が出せます。これもすでにリンクした [チャージポンプ](https://analogista.jp/chargepump/) で解説されていまっせ。当たり前レベルだと思うんだけど、それにあなたが納得できないとしたら、どこがどうなぜ納得できないのか書いてくれないと読者的には答えようがないです。

Comment: 774RR様　いつもコメントありがとう御座います。　2.5Vというのは、コンデンサに溜まる電圧だと思うのですがなぜ2.5Vなのかは自分の勉強不足のため分かりません。 質問に対する回答の際で、"同様 GND に 5V 充電済みコンデンサを逆乗せしたら -5V が出せます"というところが分かりません。いきなり、逆乗せという言葉を頂いのですが、逆乗せとは 何でしょうか？　電気回路においては、実世界にあるものを反映しているので電気が発生するということは、常にプラスの世界しかないと思うのですがなぜそのようなことが起こるでしょうか？　完全な未熟者なので基本からご教授して頂くと大変嬉しいです。よろしくお願い致します

Comment: 電子は常にマイナスですよ？　うーん。何度も書いていますが電圧って相対的なものです。こっちから見たらプラスで、あっちから見たらマイナスなんてのはごく普通のこと。 // 「基礎からご教授」となると本が１冊どころでなく必要なので SO 掲示板でやるのは不可能。自分がわかっていないことが何なのか見つめなおす（わからないと丸投げするのでなく）のは理解への最短経路だと思うのです。で、わからないところをピンポイントで訊ねることができるといいですね。 // とりあえず今この発振回路については忘れてしまいましょう。別の回路のほうが簡単に理解できるはずです（って既に書いたよね）

Comment: そう、例えば「なぜこの解説で突然 `2.5V` なんて謎の数値が現れたのでしょうか？」という質問を別途挙げてみるのもよいかもしれないっス。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。　コンデンサがプラス方向にもマイナス方向にもそれぞれ2.5Vずつ充電、放電できるという理解が抜けていたのでこの質問をさせていただいたのですが理解できました。また次回もコメントを頂けて助けて貰えれると嬉しいです。

Comment: なぜ `2.5V` で充放電が止まってしまうのかはわかっていますか？　この回路（というよりは、この回路ではない正しい回路）の動作を理解するうえで最重要ポイントなのですが。ゆえに、本の解説というか回路というかが誤っているのが致命傷っス。

Comment: コンデンサの充電と放電が出来る電圧が、それぞれ2.5Vと-2.5Vまでの容量しかないと思うのですがいかでしょうか？

Comment: 採点：その 2.5V がどこから来たのかが含まれていないので部分点０っス。コメントで質疑応答を続けるのはよくないので、まだ疑問があるなら別途投稿してください。

Comment: @774RR ちなみに一応、書籍では簡単のために閾値を2.5Vとすることが書かれています。

Comment: シュミットトリガにおいて[閾値を2.5Vとする]なんて書いてあるのであれば窓から投げ捨てろ（古）ってことになりますね。